# Select records older than latest 100 records from database

Tags: sql, mysql

My issue here is that i want to populate all the records except latest 100 records in the database. What could be the best approach to accomplish this?

Comment: The last 100, by what criterion? And what do you mean by "populate"?

Comment: I need it in various locations of my project, for instance i've a table with ID, Title, Content, Time, Status.

Comment: by saying populate i mean select or extract from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using limit cause

```
  SELECT  *
    FROM    Table 
    order by id desc 
    limit 101 , totalrecords
```

Here id is auto increment field of your table

Comment: I've tried the similar method. But it didn't work for me. Are you sure about this?

Comment: SELECT `post_tmp_tbl`.* FROM `post_tmp_tbl` WHERE (status = 'draft') ORDER BY `post_date` desc LIMIT 100 OFFSET 505

Comment: [bore-mode-on]101th record - end is `LIMIT 100, ...` [bore-mode-off]

Comment: @Aqeel Ahmad: your query is not similar. `LIMIT 505 OFFSET 100` is what you need.

Comment: by setting offset i'm telling that i need records till end. i've calculated total records previously so setting offset with help of total records.

Comment: @Aqeel Ahmad: again: you composed wrong query. By setting offset you're specifying **OFFSET**.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    Table t LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  ID
            FROM    Table
            ORDER BY ID DESC
            LIMIT 100
        ) top100    ON   t.ID = top100.ID
WHERE   top100.ID IS NULL
```

Where `ID` would be the column to identify the order (latest) and `Table` from where you wish to select

Comment: This one seems to be pretty slow. Isn't it?

Comment: Depends on your indexes. You do have indexes corret?

Comment: if you wanted to use subqueries, why don't you just find the `ID` of 100th record and select everything with `ID` < than found one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM Table
 WHERE ID < (SELECT ID
               FROM Table
           ORDER BY ID DESC
              LIMIT 99, 1)
```